# Is there a way to insert into a table with the values in array form?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I want to insert a new entry into a table, and I get each column value as the index of an array. So when I try to add it I do this:

```py
query = """INSERT INTO table VALUES(?, ?, ?)"""

cursor.execute(query, (data,))

connection.commit()
```

I also have to do the same thing for bigger data lists, so a nicer way than calling data[0], data[1], data[2] would be highly appreciated

Comment: what exactly is the issue? the code you show here would be the way to insert a sequence of values

Comment: @aws_apprentice I get a ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type

Comment: let's see some sample data then, as well as definition of the table

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure if I get you right when you say **I get each column value as the index of an array** but suppose your table person has firstname, lastname, age columns and your data is something like following

data = [["Hans", "Muster", 23], ["Jane", "Doe", 46], ["John", "Doe", 26]]

Two possible short ways to achieve insert would be..

**Option 1 - You can iterate and save one record at a time**

```
# get connection and cursor object
query= "INSERT INTO PERSON (FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, AGE) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
for rec in data:
    record = tuple(rec)
    cursor.execute(query, record)    
#handle commit or rollback as necessary
```

**Option 2 - you can use executemany to save all records in one go**

```
# get connection and cursor object   
query= "INSERT INTO PERSON (FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, AGE) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
tupleRecords = [tuple(rec) for rec in data]  
cursor.executemany(query, tupleRecords)
#handle commit or rollback as necessary
```

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like below to insert a list of values. Source:
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_insert.asp

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="yourusername",
  passwd="yourpassword",
  database="mydatabase"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

sql = "INSERT INTO customers (name, address) VALUES (%s, %s)"
val = [
  ('Peter', 'Lowstreet 4'),
  ('Amy', 'Apple st 652'),
  ('Hannah', 'Mountain 21'),
  ('Michael', 'Valley 345'),
  ('Sandy', 'Ocean blvd 2'),
  ('Betty', 'Green Grass 1'),
  ('Richard', 'Sky st 331'),
  ('Susan', 'One way 98'),
  ('Vicky', 'Yellow Garden 2'),
  ('Ben', 'Park Lane 38'),
  ('William', 'Central st 954'),
  ('Chuck', 'Main Road 989'),
  ('Viola', 'Sideway 1633')
]

mycursor.executemany(sql, val)

mydb.commit()

print(mycursor.rowcount, "was inserted.")
```

Comment: OP has to clarify and provide some sample data given that the error they are getting is due not to how they are performing the operation, but the data itself